# Link on wiki page to Excel document that opens in Excel Online

Tags: 2013, excel, wiki, hyperlink

On a wiki page, I would like to create a link to an Excel document stored in the Documents folder on SharePoint, that opens the Excel file in Excel Online.

When I create the link using Insert -> Link -> From SharePoint, I can select the Excel document. However, when clicking on the link, my browser (IE10) downloads the Excel file to my local hard drive.

I would like the file to open in my browser in Excel Online.
Is there a way to do this?

We use SharePoint 2013.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Append Web=1 to the url to instruct it where to open. 
Of course you have to have all the prereqs in place.

```
/PWA/ProjectBICenter/Documents/AllXLDashboards.xlsx?Web=1
```

Opens it in Excel Services web page

```
/PWA/ProjectBICenter/Documents/AllXLDashboards.xlsx?Web=0
```

Opens it in excel

Comment: You made my day also !!

Comment: Thank you! Worked like a charm in SharePoint Online

Answer (score 1):

Check the settings in the document library your Excel file is hosted in. In Settings -> Advanced Settings, you have should have "Open in the browser" as your default open behavior.

EDIT: If the above doesn't work, change the link's behavior (Page --> Edit --> Link) to "Open in new tab." This should force the document to open in Excel Online.

Comment: Alas, this didn't help.
When I click on the Excel file in the Documents folder, it indeed opens in Excel Online. However, when making a link on a wiki page the way I describe above, my browser still downloads the file instead of opening it in Excel Online.
Same behaviour with a link of the form [[List:Documents/mydoc.xlsx]]

Comment: Have you tried checking "Open in new tab" in the Link behavior? I looked over my setup again and I have that feature turned on, that may be what opens it in the browser in the first place.

Comment: "Open in new tab" doesn't change the behaviour :-(

Answer (score 0):

Try to Change the Stylesheets as described here: http://www.andrewjbillings.com/sharepoint-20102013-content-query-web-part-please-open-in-office-web-apps-ugh-i-loathe-you-right-now/

Comment: Can you please add brief details from the link. Links tend to break in future.