# Adobe Acrobat documents continue to open in web browser

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have a situation with

1. Web application general setting "Browser File Handing" set to strict in the general settings. Also tried changing to Permissive, did not help.
2. Site collection "Open Documents in Client Applications by Default" feature Enabled
3. Document library advanced setting "Default open behavior for browser-enabled documents" set to Open in the client application.

The documents still open in the browser. Any suggestions?

Comment: This can also be a client machine setting where the reader add-in opens files downloaded in a browser. or perhaps play with Web=0 like here: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/123657/link-on-wiki-page-to-excel-document-that-opens-in-excel-online/125045#125045

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this to the respective view page through the designer worked.

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script> 

<script type="text/jscript">

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a[onclick*='DispEx']").each( function(data){
        var href = this.href;
        this.href = '/sites/MySite/_layouts/download.aspx?SourceURL=' + this.href;
    });
    $("a[onclick*='DispEx']").removeAttr('onclick');
});
</script>
```