# Opening Excel sheets from the browser

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-server, excel, excel-services, browser-compatibility

I have an interesting issue that I'm more or less looking to find out if it's possible to fix or not.

We have a 2013 site that uses Excel Services and a custom webpart to expose these Excel reports that are stored in doc libraries. The web part gives a basic tree-style navigation and when you click on a report it opens the workbook in another web part. The Excel sheets work fine but when you click Open in Excel, it opens up fine but then in the browser this pops up:

[image: Excel Services]

If you click the highlighted part, the workbook in SharePoint closes and goes back to the document library that the workbook is saved to. If you close the pop up by clicking the X, it stays open, which is what we want. My question is this: **Is there a way to not have this pop up appear and to just leave the workbook open in the browser?**

I tried looking for an answer to this already but it's incredibly hard to find relevant materials because all of the results are just about fixing issues with the sheets opening. Everything is working fine for us we just want to know if we have the option to disable this pop up from appearing.

**Note:** I do not want to change the behavior for opening Excel files. I want them to open in the browser and have the option to open in excel, just without having this pop up that closes the browser version. It's also interesting to note that we are getting the behavior we want when it's on a 2010 site (and 2010 excel services with Office 2013) but in SP2013 with Office 2013 we get that pop up. I'm assuming it's a change in how Excel services works across the two versions.

Comment: Can you suppress this popup using jQuery? steps: use developer toolbar to look at the function call on client click for the tree with excels. Can you override it? you might probably want to debug the default Javascript for this to understand the underlying functionality. This would still be a workaround and not a solution for stopping the popup. You can look in this direction if you cannot find any other. Thanks.

Comment: What are the URLs you are using as the links to the workbooks?

Comment: @ghangas It's through a third-party web part that displays the workbooks in a tree-structure, so I'm not entirely sure how the links are getting constructed and displayed but I can take a look. Would the URLs give any indication on this behavior? I'm assuming the URLs just point to the files in the document libraries.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/123657/link-on-wiki-page-to-excel-document-that-opens-in-excel-online/125045#125045 You can design URLs to attempt to force behavior. You may be fighting with a design decision and not with SP

Comment: I'm not sure if that is relevant here; we are getting the behavior we want with respect to the workbooks opening in the browser. It's only when the user clicks the Open in Excel button that we get the pop up that we want to prevent. Again, the behavior we want it there, we just don't want the popup saying "We're opening your workbook in Excel" to appear. I'll take a look though and see if I can play around with either JS or the URLs.

Answer (score 1):

I think you will not face the same pop-up dialog when you open the SharePoint site from within the internet explorer, though the problem is a web browser oriented one.
Also the behavior changes when using Mozilla Firefox.